# Js : hide/show of windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me about tutorials or code to do or create the same of hide/show of windows in the bottom left of page of this site (Why work with us?) :

```
http://blueowlcreative.com/wp/aqua/
```

Any Idea?

Comment: You want to imitate the "Why work with us?" box of the website ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/,  http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) for this.